# React useReducer not updating state in realated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have not used useReducer much.
I have a component with useReducer .it has to increment and decrement button .when I click state gets updated and we can see change ..but only for that component the second also using the same state doesn't get updated ..until I click inc or dec button

```
import React, { Component,useReducer } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
export const appstate = {
    foo: 99
};

export function freducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
        appstate.foo+=1;
      return {...appstate};
    case 'decrement':
        appstate.foo-=1;
        return {...appstate};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export function Dap(prop) {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(freducer, appstate)
console.log(state);
return (
    <>
      foo: {state.foo}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}

render(<>
       <Dap />
        <hr/>
        <Dap />
</>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Code and working present at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wrql5k

I had already gone with many links of stack overflow..not able to understand.

Comment: Because you have `two different states` in `two instances` of Dap component.
If you would like to use only one state, you can [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: so if i dont change instance in freducer ...it dosent even get updated..so how can i fix it @LongNguyen

Comment: If you would like to use only one state, you can [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: but  if i just list state and pass it as props then whats use of useReducer...is there any other way

Comment: You need to create a component to hold the shared state then create two instances of Dap on this. This is [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5duso9)

Comment: Or you can use ReactContext or global state management (like redux)